# how to make different layout for tablet in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm thinking about making different layout for Tablet/iPad version but I'm new to Flutter so I'm not really sure how to make it. I'll be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion on how to do it.

Right now If I run on Tablet, my cards are stretch out and I'm trying to fix it right now. Also I'm trying to add a divider and column on the right side (attached pic of the design below) so that I can add more text.

This is my cards

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 180,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Card(
          elevation: 8.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Column(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10,0),
              child: Row(children: [
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> DetailsPage("Favorite")));
                  },
                ))
              ]),
            ),
            Divider(color: Colors.black),
            Row(children: [
              //Legend
              tileWidget(TileItem(
                  topText: "Top",
                  middleText: "Middle",
                  bottomText: "Bottom")),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red, 
                height: 60, width: 2),
                (tileItems.length < 1) ? null : tileWidget(tileItems[0]),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green, 
                height: 60, width: 2),
                (tileItems.length < 2) ? null : tileWidget(tileItems[1]),
              Container(
                color: Colors.black26, height: 60, width: 2),
              (tileItems.length < 3) ? null : tileWidget(tileItems[2])
            ]),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the screen width, use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`
Make a widget for any width under 600dp (ie. the phone) and another for any width above (ie. the tablet).
Then your code will look something like this:

```
body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {

        if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600) {
          isTablet= true;
        } else {
          isTablet= false;
        } etc...
      }
```

Here is a helpful resource: https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434

Comment: This is not working, in case of landscape orientation of iPhone. Then, isTablet is marked as true, but it is not correct, it is just landscape orientation of the phone.